# Combining and optimizing reservations in database

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql

If got a reservation table containing reservations for assets. A reservation can exist for a certain period of time, possibly spanning multiple days.

I want to combine these reservations for a certain period of time to get:
1 - an overview of the number of assets required to accomodate the reservations: `n`;
2 - a resulting table which holds a row id `r` where `r` <= `n`

That sounds strange, but let me explain by giving an example.
Lets consider these three reservations (simplified for demonstrating purposes):

```
res1    2015-04-20 14:00:00    2015-04-21 11:00:00
res2    2015-04-21 13:00:00    2015-04-21 15:00:00
res3    2015-04-21 11:00:00    2015-04-21 14:00:00
```

If we put this in a graph displaying *2015-04-21 9:00* till *2015-04-21 15:00*. So reservation 1 gets trimmed, and as a result we get this, with an X indicating a reservation.

```
           9    10   11   12   13   14
res1       X    X    -    -    -    -
res2       -    -    -    -    X    X
res3       -    -    X    X    X    -
```

If we, as humans, look at this table we would combine reservation 1 and 3 to be on one row (or asset). And the second row would be only containing reservation 2 (and be asset number2).

So `n = 2` for this period of time.

The resulting table I want to produce is the following, adding a column holding an identifier.

```
res1    2015-04-20 14:00:00    2015-04-21 11:00:00   1
res2    2015-04-21 13:00:00    2015-04-21 15:00:00   2
res3    2015-04-21 11:00:00    2015-04-21 14:00:00   1
```

Why do I want these two results one might ask. Well with the first result (the `n`) I could see if a new reservation would be possible for a time period giving the number of assets available during that period. And secondly with the resulting table you can built a rack containing combined reservations, optimizing the use of assets.

Preferably the two results would be produced by SQL query's (which I can store in a stored procedure). But off course some logic can also be within the PHP environment.

Comment: Don't tag products not involved.(Are you using both MySQL and Postresql?)

Comment: Well actually I am using both on two different projects concerning similar reservation questions. But for clarity sake I'll remove MySQL as postgresql is my main database system.

Comment: You need to use some kind of algorithm: foreach(rowi in 1 to n where rowi is not in any res) { create resK; while exists rowj where rowj(start) > resK(end): add rowj to resource}. You're probably better off using PHP

Comment: Thank you Simo. I already was afraid it wasn't doable in sql. How about the first result, the number of needed assets?